# Why does my Class method call work in one method but not another?

Tags: ruby, argument-passing

I am teaching myself Ruby and using a a compiler with Visual studio know as Sapphire on Steel to run the code. I am making a blackjack program for school. I created a Deck class, Card class and Player class so far. In the deck class I have a function that prints the contents of the deck and I am trying to use the same function to print the contents of a player's hand. The code calls a function of the card class getCard(), and loops the entire array. The printing method works for the printDeck() function but not for the showHand() function.

The deck object is created, and its contents are passed to an array in PlayerHand.start() function. The PlayerHand.showHand() function prints the contents of the array that the deck contents were passed to.

Could someone please help me figure out why? Any and all help would be appreciated

```
#Zach Albright
#4-11-2013
#Black Jack

class Card
def initialize(suit, value)
    @suit = suit
    @value = value
end

def getCard()
    puts "#{@suit}: #{@value}\n"
end

def getSuit()
    return @suit
end

def getValue()
    return @value
end
 end

 class Deck
def initialize()
    @deck = Array.new() 

    for i in 1..4
        for j in 1..13
            if i == 1
                if j == 11
                    @deck.push(Card.new("Hearts", "Jack"))
                elsif j == 12
                    @deck.push(Card.new("Hearts", "Queen"))
                elsif j == 13
                    @deck.push(Card.new("Hearts", "King"))
                else
                    @deck.push(Card.new("Hearts", j))
                end


            elsif i == 2
                if j == 11
                    @deck.push(Card.new("Spades", "Jack"))
                elsif j == 12
                    @deck.push(Card.new("Spades", "Queen"))
                elsif j == 13
                    @deck.push(Card.new("Spades", "King"))
                else
                    @deck.push(Card.new("Spades", j))
                end

            elsif i == 3
                if j == 11
                    @deck.push(Card.new("Clubs", "Jack"))
                elsif j == 12
                    @deck.push(Card.new("Clubs", "Queen"))
                elsif j == 13
                    @deck.push(Card.new("Clubs", "King"))
                else
                    @deck.push(Card.new("Clubs", j))
                end
            elsif i == 4
                if j == 11
                    @deck.push(Card.new("Diamonds", "Jack"))
                elsif j == 12
                    @deck.push(Card.new("Diamonds", "Queen"))
                elsif j == 13
                    @deck.push(Card.new("Diamonds", "King"))
                else
                    @deck.push(Card.new("Diamonds", j))
                end
            end
        end
    end

    @deck.compact
end


def printDeck()
    @deck.each do |i|
        puts i.getCard()
    end
end

def shuffleDeck()
    @deck.shuffle!
end

def drawCard()
    return @deck.pop()
end

def drawHand()
    return @deck.pop(5)
end
 end

 class PlayerHand   
def initialize()
    @pHand = Array.new()
    @pCard = Card.new("Hearts", 4)

end

def start(myDeck)
    @pHand.push(myDeck.drawHand())
end


def drawCard(myDeck)
    @pHand.push(myDeck.drawCard())
end

#still needs work to show the actual contents of the card .getCard is not working     correctly
def showHand()
    @pHand.each do |i|
        puts i.getCard()
    end
end
 end

 myCard = Card.new("Hearts", 4)
 myArray = Array.new()

 puts myCard.getCard()

 myDeck = Deck.new()
 myDeck.shuffleDeck()

 player = PlayerHand.new()
 player.start(myDeck)
 player.showHand()
```

error:
C:\Users\Zach\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\BlackJack\BlackJack\BlackJack.rb:118:in `showHand': undefined method`getCard' for # (NoMethodError)

from C:\Users\Zach\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\BlackJack\BlackJack\BlackJack.rb:117:in `each'

from C:\Users\Zach\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\BlackJack\BlackJack\BlackJack.rb:117:in `showHand'

from C:\Users\Zach\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\BlackJack\BlackJack\BlackJack.rb:133

Comment: What happens when `getCard()` is called? Is there an error?

Comment: @GavinMiller Oops forgot to put the error, I will add the error I am getting for the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies with `drawHand()` when you're calling `@deck.pop(5)` you're returning an array that holds 5 cards.

In your method `start` if you change `push` to `+` you'll be okay.

```
def start(myDeck)
    @pHand + myDeck.drawHand()
end
```

Comment: Ohhh okay that makes much more sense. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

```
block in showHand': undefined method 'getCard' for #<Array:0x007ff3799a8c28> (NoMethodError)
```

The error message is pretty clear: you're calling `Card#getCard` on an Array object, which obviously doesn't exist.

`getCard()` is an instance method of the `Card` class, which means that you can *only* call it with a `Card` object as the receiver:

```
card = Card.new
card.getCard()
```

Comment: @user1457104 which line are you talking about?

Comment: printDeck:
deck is an array

    def printDeck()
    deck.each do |i|
        puts i.getCard()
    end
    end

showHand()
pHand is an array

    def showHand()
    @pHand.each do |i|
        puts i.getCard()
    end
    end

Comment: you define `printDeck()` but you never call it. Try to call it and you'll receive the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In the start method, you're pushing the return value of myDeck.drawHand which is an array. So then when you look at the hand using each, what you're getting is this array rather than cards.  You want to do something like

```
myDeck.drawHand.each do |card|
    @pHand << card
end
```